# Unity meta files screw up facebook android builds

Tags: android, facebook-unity-sdk

I had already posted this, found a workaround and marked as answered:

[Facebook Unity SDK android barfs when project connected to Asset Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460522/facebook-unity-sdk-android-barfs-when-project-connected-to-asset-server)

But just came back to this project 3 months later, got the brand spanking new facebook SDK which has many solid changes, and it's still a problem. Come on guys, there must be some "--ignore-assets" compile option that can be included to ignore .meta files, no?

Pretty please fix :)

Comment: Um, it's been almost a week and not a peep. Is support for this plugin dead in the water? I would consider this a pretty major issue that needs to be addressed...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re72di5phM0